# Android Sqlite database is not getting updated

Tags: android, database, sqlite

After implementing this code db is not getting updated. Please help me to find the solution.

```
public void updateBook(Book book) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, book.getBook()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PUBLISHER_ID, book.getPublisherId());
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, book.getSubject());
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, book.getPrice());
    values.put(KEY_CLASS, book.getClassFor());
    values.put(KEY_CODE, book.getCode());

    // updating row
    db.execSQL(Query);

    db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{book.getId()});
    db.close();
}
```

Also tried this too.

```
String Query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_BOOKS + " SET " + KEY_NAME + "='" + book.getBook() + "', " + KEY_PUBLISHER_ID
            + "='" + book.getPublisherId() + "', " + KEY_SUBJECT + "='" + book.getSubject() + "', " + KEY_PRICE + "='" + book.getPrice() + "', " + KEY_CLASS + "='" + book.getClassFor() + "', " + KEY_CODE + "='" + book.getCode()
            + "' WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=' " + book.getId() + "'";

    // updating row
    db.execSQL(Query);
```

Comment: What did returned db.update? You can remove execSQL from first example, already doing same thing with update.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? This method is right but it might not be getting called i guess. Please upload that code too.

Comment: `KEY_ID + "=' " + book.getId() + "'"` ... isn't *KEY_ID* an **integer**? If so, it will be never equal to a **text**.

Comment: Same goes for *KEY_PUBLISHER_ID* abd *KEY_PRICE* ... it appears you're not aware of any data type other  than **text**??

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection